# Doctrine2 and ZendFramework2 - Loading Doctrine on service layers

Tags: dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm trying to load doctrine 2 into my service layers objects using the module.config.php:

```
namespace MyApp;
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'myapp_doctrine_em' => 'doctrine_em',
        ),
        'orm_driver_chain' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'MyApp' => array(
                        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                        'namespace' => __NAMESPACE__ . '\Models\Entity',
                        'paths' => array(
                            __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Models/Entity'
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        'driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'namespace' => 'MyApp\Models\Entity',
            'paths' => array('module/MyApp/src/MyApp/Models/Entity')
        ),
        'MyApp\Controller\DefaultController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'em' => 'myapp_doctrine_em',
            )
        ),
        'MyApp\Models\DefaultModel' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'em' => 'myapp_doctrine_em',
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

as seen above, when I instantiate the doctrine in the controllers, it does work, however when doing the same thing to my models, it doesn't.

Question:
- How may I proceed to load the doctrine entity manager in my models instead of passing them thru controllers?

What Am I missing?

Thank you!

### adding the model class as a sample

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class DefaultModel {

    protected $_em;

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->_em = $em;
    }

    public function getEntityManager() {
        return $this->_em;
    }

}
```

---

My Controller extends a DefaultController with a dependency injection method like:

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class MyAppController extends DefaultController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $auth = $this->getDI('MyApp\Models\AuthenticationModel');
        $auth->validate($this->getRequest()->post()->toArray());
        ...
        return new ViewModel($data);
    }

}
```

---

DefaultController:

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController,
    Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class DefaultController extends ActionController {

    protected function getDI($service) {
        $di = new Zend\Di\Di();
        $im = new Zend\Di\InstanceManager();
        $di->setInstanceManager($im);
        return $di->get($service);
    }

}
```

---

the authentication model:

```
namespace MyApp\Models;

class AuthenticationModel extends DefaultModel {

    public function validate(array $vars) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: First: are you sure you want your model to become aware of the entity manager? That sounds like an anti-pattern to me. Then: this config works only if you instantiate models through DI. What is your model class and how do you instantiate your model? Please attach some more code to give better insight.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Sorry for sounding that noobish. I am just playing around with zf2 and doctrine2. The whole idea is to keep Fat-Model/Thin-Controller. I've been playing with [link](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUserDoctrineORM)[/link] and it seems to me that they've placed their entity managers into theirs mapper classes. I just want to do the same with my ones instead of passing it thru constructor methods while instantiating the models.

Comment: I see now your service layer is in the `Models` (sub)namespace, your models are in the `Models\Entity` namespace. Your models look good, can you also post how you get the `MyApp\Models\DefaultModel` inside your controller?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time and patience. That is all my "project".

Comment: Please see my answer. As from my first question, I expected a mismatch in naming convention from your model (which is not the case) or a wrong approach when you try to pull the service from DI. That was the case, the answer should explain enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand first that everything you do with DI needs to be configured, otherwise only instantiation happens an no wiring. That means, if you "just" use a new `Zend\Di\Di` instance, you can pull objects from there, but no dependencies are resolved. Dependencies are injected when you configure DI appropriately.

This DI configuration is provided in your module config. However, your new DI instance is unaware of this config. You have two options: configure this DI instance with the configuration or use a pre-configured DI instance. I would say you are now trying to accomplish the first, while the second option is much, much easier.

A configured DI instance is injected into any `Zend\Mvc\Controller\ActionController` and available under `getLocator()`. This returns a `Zend\Di\Locator` instance and by default a `Zend\Di\Di`. From there, you can pull your service because that DI instance is configured already with your module configuration.

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class MyAppController extends DefaultController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $auth = $this->getLocator()->get('MyApp\Models\AuthenticationModel');
        $auth->validate($this->getRequest()->post()->toArray());
        ...
        return new ViewModel($data);
    }

}
```

Note I replaced your `getDI()` by `getLocator()->get()`. And therefore you can remove `MyApp\Controller\DefaultController::getDI()` and possibly even the complete `DefaultController`.